# Needs To create a widgets for websites and stand alone desktops.?

Tags: widget, desktop

i have to create widgets for whether reports and etc. to my website. what are all the needs to create widgets? is Css5 and Html enough to make a attracting widgets?? can you provide me the correct way to do that ...

Update Question :

i have got some more ideas to make widgets for websites and how we can add into our web pages. and now i have to do widgets for desktops like windows 7 desktop widgets. is it possible? and what're all the needs to make it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: asking how to create a widget is like asking how to cook a meal....do you want pizza? this is a very abstract question

Comment: @trey..wow nice!! i think it is pretty much simple.ok any way,am very newable to web development. thats y getting too much of confusion. soon i'll come forward with right knowledge....

Answer (score 0):

The widgets are generally *not developed by the people who run the websites they appear on*. Instead the weather widget might come from a weather site that provides data to. The widget is provided as code for web developers to paste into their site. These widgets refer to the maintained weather website (images, data, etc...). Some of them allow for **a small level of customization**, so you can use your own colour palette to make it blend with your site, or toggle rounded corners etc...

As a start [a quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=weather%20widget%20copy%20paste) brought me to [google's gadgets page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/gadgets/foryourpage/index.html) which will get you started. I don't doubt that they are customizable through some minimal CSS. Changing borders and such.

Comment: hmm thanks for the explanations.... but i dont want to use the codes through websites. now i got some idea about how to make it ourself. thank u once again.